# iterating through hsqldb cursor

Tags: cursor, iteration, hsqldb

What is the syntax for HSQLDB cursor iteration?
I know how to declare and open a cursor, but in other dialects, after opening a cursor you usually do something along the lines of

```
WHILE "more rows" DO
    FETCH  NEXT FROM c INTO @var1, @var2, ...
    "do something with vars here"
END WHILE
```

I was unable to find any example of moving cursor to the next row.
Am I looking at this from  a wrong angle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operations using cursors are supported within SQL routines (FUNCTION and PROCEDURE) using a FOR loop.

```
for_label: 
FOR SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM ATABLE WHERE COL3='something' DO
    SET VAR1 = COL1;
    SET VAR2 = COL2;
    -- do something
END FOR for_label;
```

See http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlroutines-chapt.html#src_psm_for_statement

Comment: I'm really trying to run for loops in HSQL but I always end up with this error: `unexpected token: FOR_LABEL / Error Code: -5581 / State: 42581`. Actually, this error came from that very exceprt right there.

Comment: @cbalden check the statement before the FOR_LABEL to make sure it is terminated. If you cannot get it to work, open a new question.